# Hacklang Higher order functions for Collections

Tags: arrays, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions, hhvm, hacklang

Do Hacklang Collections have higher order functions such as `Reduce`, `Some`, `All` or an easy way to implement such methods. The Collection I am most focused on is the Vector. It seems to only have `Map` and `Filter`. The others would help in writing more clean looking functional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full information on the different Hack collections is best seen on the [API docs for `Vector`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/Vector/) (and other classes).

I also only see `->map` and `->filter`, though writing a utility function to do `reduce` yourself isn't particularly difficult, of course.